# Latex writ only until the middle of the page

Tags: latex, pdflatex, biblatex

am try to type a a pseudo code of an algorithme in latex it work fine but it just writ until the midle . and the rest stay empty .. here is the source

```
\documentclass{IEEETran}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{GPX operator}
\hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Input} s1 = $\lbrace V^{1}_{1}; ... ; V^{1}_{k}\rbrace$ and  s2 = $\lbrace V^{2}_{1}; ... ; V^{2}_{k}\rbrace$ - parent solutions. \\
 \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Output} $ s = \lbrace V_{1}; ... ; V_{k}\rbrace$ - offspring solution. \\
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For {$l(1\leq l \leq k)$}
\If{($l$ is odd)}
\State A=1

\Else
\State  A=2;
 \EndIf
 \State choose $i$ such that $V^{A}_{i}$  has a maximum cardinality
\State $V_{l}$=$V^{A}_{i}$
\State remove the vertices of  $V_{l}$ from $s1$ and $s2$
\EndFor
\State Assign randomly the vertices of $V - (V_{1} \cup ... \cup V_{k})$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and here is what i get :[image]

Comment: I do not understand your problem. The last line of your source and formatted text are both "Assign randomly...". Why do you say "it just writes until the middle and the rest stays empty"?

Comment: i mean the horizontal middle ... in algorithm 2 in the input statement  it writ parent and then go ti the next line

Comment: Default mode of IEEEtran is twocolumn. Compile with \documentclass[onecolumn]{IEEEtran} if it's what you want.

Comment: am new in latex ... and your suggestion work great .. thank u .. put it in a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default mode of IEEEtran is twocolumn. Compile with `\documentclass[onecolumn]{IEEEtran}` if it's what you want.